# Two different numbering styles for equations in the same document

Tags: equations, numbering

Earlier in the document, there's some equations labeled like this:

```
(1)  (some space) \frac{1}{/2}=0.5

(2)  (some space) hi
```

Now, I want to do something like this and switch the equation number and start over:

```
(a)  (some space) hello
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are those really equations? Or is it just an enumeration that just happens to have math in some items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %% for \eqref macro
\setlength\textwidth{2in} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \frac{1}{2}=0.5 \label{eq:1} \end{equation} 
\begin{equation} \mbox{hi} \end{equation}

\setcounter{equation}{0}  % reset the equation counter
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}} % change numbering from arabic to alphabetic

Now, I want to do something like this and switch the equation number and start over:
\begin{equation} \mbox{hello} \label{eq:a} \end{equation}

Here are cross-references to equations \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:a}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 You might add some labels to show this work correctly too.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use two different (custom) environments each with their own counters? `equation-arabic`, `equation-alpha` for example?

Comment: @AndrewSwann - Thanks for this suggestion, I'll incorporate in in the answer.

Comment: @Thruston - Let's see if the OP weighs in on what he/she is trying to achieve with this change in equation numbering system.

Comment: Thanks!  It's really interesting though because this only works if I don't include the fleqn.  This post is really helpful though.

Comment: @user54689 - Which document class do you employ? Possibly one that doesn't recognize the option `fleqn`?